# Add content in the middle of notepad (existing)

Tags: php, insert

I have a .txt file with following content.

```
[{"key": "HR", "value": "test@gmail.com"}, {"key": "Team Leader", "value": "test1@gmail.com"}, {"key": "PM", "value": "test3@gmail.com"}, {"key": "CEO", "value": "test4@gmail.com"}]
```

Now ,using php if i want to add another one value like
{"key": "new_emailid", "value":"test5@gmail.com"}

The output should be lik this

```
[{"key": "HR", "value": "test@gmail.com"}, {"key": "Team Leader", "value": "test1@gmail.com"}, {"key": "PM", "value": "test3@gmail.com"}, {"key": "CEO", "value": "test4@gmail.com"}, {"key": "new_emailid", "value":"test5@gmail.com"}]
```

In other words, how to add content inside the square bracket of the exisiting .txt file. Is it possible to insert a content in between the brackets. Please help me
Thanks -
Haan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dealing with JSON the safest way would be to read the txt file and load it as JSON, add a new item, and save it back. Something like this:

```
$data = File_Get_Contents ( 'data.txt' );
$data = JSon_Decode ( $data, true );
$data[] = Array ( 'key' => 'new_emailid', 'value' => 'test5@gmail.com' );
$data = JSon_Encode ( $data );
File_Put_Contents ( 'data.txt', $data );
```

Comment: You really capitalise your functions like that? This is why PHP should have enforced case sensitivity on function names! :P

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure `json_decode()` returns an object, not an array. You can set its second argument to `TRUE` to return an associative array.

Comment: Yep, I really do that. An old habit from the .NET days I guess :) And you are correct about jsone_decode returning an object, I'll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot man. no words. worked perfect. u r too very awesome.. thanks a lot fnd